# Python program hangs when reading from serial port after calling raw_input

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using Python 2.7.4 and pyserial to communicate with a device (basically an Arduino). For some reason my program hangs whenever I try to read data from the device and from the console in a loop using the following code,:

```
xbm = serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=BAUD)
for i in range(20):
  alldata = ''
  s = raw_input('vin {}: '.format(i))
  vin_y.append(float(s))
  xbm.flushInput()
  bytes_read = 0
  while bytes_read < (packet_size*(avg_samples+1)):
    if xbm.inWaiting() > 0:
      read_size = xbm.inWaiting() # stop bit
      data = xbm.read(read_size)
      bytes_read += read_size
```

When I try to get my data this way, I get the data from raw_input correctly, but then my program hangs. If I comment out

```
s = raw_input('vin {}: '.format(i))
vin_y.append(float(s))
```

I get all of the desired from my device, but then obviously I'm not getting the user input I want. Also, if I move those lines to before I open the serial port, I can get still read from it correctly. Based on this, I'm guessing that something on the input buffer is messing with the way I'm reading from the serial port. I've tried clearing the input buffer to get rid of any newline characters from entering data, but that hasn't worked (or I'm just doing it wrong). I know what I want to do is possible; hopefully I'm just missing something small.

Comment: Are you sure `raw_input` is the right function? Don't you want to `read` from `xbm`?

Comment: I'm sure. This code is for calibration testing, so I'm taking values off a multimeter and entering them as my vin_y values. Then I need to see what the xbm is measuring for the vin_x values (not shown) by reading over the serial connection. Then at the end I am doing a linear fit on the two sets of data (which is why this needs to loop).